# Creating a custom primary_key field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I originally had the standard default `id` field for my Django model. However I want to switch to a random 10-15 alphanumerical string.

Here's the string if you're curious (it works):

```
def random_string(chars=string.ascii_letters + string.digits):
    size = random.randrange(10, 15)
    return str(''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size)))
```

And here's my model. I simply added in the field and did `migrate` & `makemigrations`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=18, primary_key=True, default=random_string())
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Expectedly it wan't a smooth changeover - when I make a Post, I get the following `non_field_error`:

```
Non Errors: <bound method BaseForm.non_field_errors of <PostForm bound=False, valid=False, fields=(content;id;user)>>
[20/Mar/2018 09:38:37] "POST /post/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11482
```

**views**

```
def post(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form_post = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form_post.is_valid():
            instance = form_post.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user

            instance.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            form_post = PostForm()
            print('Errors:', form_post.errors) #prints nothing
            print('Non Errors:', form_post.non_field_errors) 

        context = {
            'form_post': form_post,
        }

        return render(request, 'post/post.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/signup/")
```

Can anyone tell me why I get that `non_field_error`? Here's the accompanying form to the model:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'content',
            'id',
            'user'
        ]
```

Comment: You are currently initializing default with a value `default=random_string()`. I suppose you want to use a callable (`default=random_string`) so it gets called every time a new object is created ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#default).

Comment: Just changed `random_string()` to `random_string` but I still get the same `<bound method BaseForm.non_field_errors of <PostForm bound=False, valid=False, fields=(content;id;user)>>
` error

Answer (score 1):

`non_field_errors` is a method, not a regular attribute as `errors` is:

```
print('Non Errors:', form_post.non_field_errors())
```